# Are the specific actual rules of the Rank Meter known?

Tags: splatoon-2

Regarding the Rank Meter in Ranked in *Splatoon 2*,

[image]

Here's the problem:

1. Say you have one or two cracks. In fact, sometimes when you lose a match, ***it does not*** give another crack.
2. Indeed sometimes when you are are on three cracks and you lose, it ***does not*** demote/pushback...you seem to get one more free chance.

(Note, I mean in normal games with no disconnects. Of course, when there's a disconnect you are not penalized.)

3. Moreover, when you win the ***amount of movement to the right*** seems to ***vary***.  Sometimes a little, sometimes a lot.
4. It does not seem to relate to your personal performance in the game (whether number of kills, coverage, time in control etc).

Does anyone know what the **actual exact rules** are for

(1)  When or if you get a crack

(2)  How much it moves when you win

It genuinely seems somewhat random.

I checked the printed handbook and it has no information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Splatoon Wiki](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Rank#Rank_meter)

> The rank meter is represented internally as a number between 0 and 100. The numbers that track filling of the rank meter and those that track cracks are **two separate systems**; winning matches adds points to the number system that fills the rank meter, while **losing adds points to a different number system that contributes to cracks on the meter**.
>
> A full rank meter is represented by the "fill" number reaching 100, which causes the player to rank up. **The rank meter breaks when the "crack" number reaches 100. Every 25 points is equivalent to one crack on the meter**.
>
> How the player gains points that affect these numbers depends on the probability of winning a match in Ranked, as determined by the game. The number of "fill" points gained for winning a match that the game determined was a likely victory for the player's team will be lower than that gained for one with a lower probability. Conversely, **losing a match that the game determines the player had a high chance to win will add a high number of points to the "crack" number compared to one where the player was less likely to win.**

(emphasis mine)

So what the wiki seems to be saying is that the cracks merely serve as a visual indicator for the second number, much like the progress bar. I was unable to find values, but it probably has something to do with the difference between the ranks of each team and not just random chance.

To answer your questions:

(1) You get a crack for every 25 points in the "crack" number

(2) It moves an amount determined by how likely you were to win the game.

Comment: Ahh !   The secret seems to be *"depends on the probability of winning a match in Ranked, as determined by the game"*.   Ah hah!

Comment: sent a bounty..